# How to get voters lists from all linked issues

Tags: java, jira, jira-plugin

I am trying to create a JIRA plugin that does the following:

1. For each issue, takes all linked issues which are linked by "duplicates" or "is duplicated by" (or other predefined link types).
2. For each such issue, get a list (not necessarily a `List` object) of the voters on that issue.

My problem is that the javadoc has little to no information. Following a tutorial, I currently have:

```
public class VotersCount extends AbstractJiraContextProvider {

    @Override
    public Map<String, Integer> getContextMap(User user, JiraHelper jiraHelper) {

        Map<String, Integer> contextMap = new HashMap<>();
        Issue currentIssue = (Issue) jiraHelper.getContextParams().get("issue");
//      Issue[] linkedIssues = currentIssue.getLinkedIssuesBy(...); //Step 1 mock code
//      Voter[] voters = linkedissues[3].getVoters(); //Step 2 mock code
        int count = voters.length; //Pretend there is some calculation here
        contextMap.put("votersCount", count);
        return contextMap;
    }
}
```

(and I use `votersCount` in the .vm file.)

However, I see no explanation in the javadocs for `AbstractJiraContextProvider` and `getContextMap` so I'm not even sure if it's the right approach.

In my own research I found the class `ViewVoters` which has the method `Collection<UserBean> getVoters()`, which is something I can work with, but I don't know how to obtain or construct such an object in a way which will interact with a given issue.

I am looking for a working code to replace my 2 lines of mock code.

Comment: Apparently there is a [tutorial](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Performing+Issue+Operations#PerformingIssueOperations-Retrievingissuelinks) covering some of what I need for step 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using the following:

1. To get issues linked to `Issue issue` by specified link types:

   ```
   LinkCollection linkCollection = ComponentAccessor.getIssueLinkManager().getLinkCollectionOverrideSecurity(issue);
   Set<IssueLinkType> linkTypes = linkCollection.getLinkTypes();
   // Perform operations on the set to get the issues you want.
   for (IssueLinkType linkType : linkTypes) {
       List<Issue> l1 = linkCollection.getOutwardIssues(linkType.getName());
       List<Issue> l2 = linkCollection.getInwardIssues(linkType.getName());
   }
   ```
2. To get all the voters on `Issue issue`:

   ```
   ComponentAccessor.getVoteManager().getVoterUserkeys(issue);
   ```

I was later shown that one can extend `CalculatedCFType` and override `getValueFromIssue` which hands you the current issue as a parameter instead of the using

```
Issue currentIssue = (Issue) jiraHelper.getContextParams().get("issue");
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Use one of the methods from IssueLinkService. Maybe [getIssueLinks](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/bc/issue/link/IssueLinkService.html#getIssueLinks(com.atlassian.crowd.embedded.api.User,%20com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue))

2) [issueVoterAccessor.getVoterUserkeys](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/issue/vote/IssueVoterAccessor.html#getVoterUserkeys(com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue))

Instances of IssueLinkService and IssueVoterAccessor should be injected as parameters to constructor of your VotersCount.